# Rufus Scheduler not running when rails server runs as daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rufus-scheduler

I have a a rails app that is using Rufus Scheduler.  When I turn on the rails server with:

```
rails s --port=4000
```

Rufus scheduler runs its tasks. If I run the rails server with:

```
rails s --port=4000 --daemon
```

Rufus no longer does its tasks.  I added a couple of log messages.  Here is the schedule code:

```
class AtTaskScheduler

  def self.start
    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

    p "Starting Attask scheduler"

    scheduler.every('5m') do
      # test sending hip chat message
      issue = Issue.new
      issue.post_to_hipchat("Starting sync with AtTask","SYNC")
      p "Launching Sync"
      Issue.synchronize
    end

  end

end
```

Hipchat never gets the message from the scheduler and the log never gets the statement "Launching Sync".

Any ideas on what may be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is documentation of this issue in the [rufus-scheduler docs](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#rails-server--d):

> There is the handy `rails server -d` that starts a development Rails as
>   a daemon. The annoying thing is that the scheduler as seen above is
>   started in the main process that then gets forked and daemonized. The
>   rufus-scheduler thread (and any other thread) gets lost, no scheduling
>   happens.
>
> I avoid running `-d` in development mode and bother about daemonizing
>   only for production deployment.
>
> These are two well crafted articles on process daemonization, please
>   read them:
>
> - http://www.mikeperham.com/2014/09/22/dont-daemonize-your-daemons/
> - http://www.mikeperham.com/2014/07/07/use-runit/
>
> If anyway, you need something like `rails server -d`, why not try `bundle exec unicorn -D`
>   instead? In my (limited) experience, it worked out of the box (well,
>   had to add `gem 'unicorn'` to `Gemfile` first).

Comment: Thank you!  This is a great intermediary step.  I'm reading your articles now and will determine a better way to move forward.